# Ansible EC2 dynamic inventory - tag containing a hyphen

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to run an ad-hoc `ansible` command on hosts that have been tagged as `Name = foo-bar` (notice the hyphen). When I run:

`ansible tag_Name_foo_bar -i ec2.py -m ping`

I get: `No hosts matched`

However, there is such a host. If I run the same command against a host that is tagged with a name not containing a hyphen, it works fine, e.g for a host that is tagged `Name = foobar`, the following works:

`ansible tag_Name_foobar -i ec2.py -m ping`

H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your ansible version? It works for me. According to [Example: AWS EC2 External Inventory Script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script)

**Tags**

> Each instance can have a variety of key/value pairs associated with it
>   called Tags. The most common tag key is ‘Name’, though anything is
>   possible. Each key/value pair is its own group of instances, again
>   with special characters converted to underscores, in the format
>   tag_KEY_VALUE e.g. tag_Name_Web can be used as is
>   tag_Name_redis-master-001 becomes tag_Name_redis_master_001
>   tag_aws_cloudformation_logical-id_WebServerGroup becomes
>   tag_aws_cloudformation_logical_id_WebServerGroup

It is possible ansible's ec2 cache is not refreshed. Try:

```
ec2.py --refresh-cache
```

and then run your ansible command again. When I changed my instance tag name to `foo_bar`, ot worked correctly.